# Drush: how to set access to MySQL

Tags: 7, drush, database

When I run command "drush status" I cannot see any MySQL settings (user, password or database).

I cannot use commands like "core-quick-drupal" because it requires access to MySQL, before /sites/default/settings.php is created.

How can I set such MySQL connection?

I have installed drush in linux in directory /user/share/php

When I install Drupal from web browser interface, I can see that database support is enabled. I have problem only when installing drupal via drush

Comment: have you tried `drush help site-install`?

Answer (score 2):

core-quick-drupal doesn't require mysql, it would use something like sqlite. drush site-install allows you to specify config options like the mysql connection.  For example:

```
drush site-install mysite --db-url=mysql://user:pass@server/dbname
```